# Laravel: Controller class Global variable returns null in class function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-8.2

I'm a java developer; New to Laravel and PHP both. I learned how to define a global variable in Laravel controller class and used it as such. But it returns null in all other functions.

I have a class variable `$person` in my `AddPersInfoController.php`.

I initialize it first in a function because I need this ID to be saved with every record in different tables (handled by different functions in same controller) of the Database. But when I try to use it in any other function at the time of submitting `form`, it returns `null`.

Initialization function is called in `get` route as such:

Route in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/add_all/{persId?}',[AddPersInfoController::class,'add_all'])->name('add_all');
```

My `AddPersInfoController.php` controller

```
class AddPersInfoController extends Controller
{   
    private $person     ;
    
    public  function add_all( int $user_id){

        $pers   = $this->person = Pers_info::find($user_id);
                dd($pers); // This shows all values fetched from Database
                .
                .
        }
```

Here I initialize it and copy it into a local variable `pers` to pass it to the `view` using `compact()` method with a few other local variables.

In the `view`, I enter the data in other fields as required and then save them using a `post` route.

In `web.php`

```
Route::post('/add/prom_hist',[AddPersInfoController::class,'addPromHist'])->name('add_prom_hist');
```

`AddPersInfoController.php` controller

```
public function addPromHist(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate ( $request, [
            ......
        ]);
        
        dd($this->person); // This returns null.

                $promHist = new Prom_history();
        
        $promHist-> pers_info_id     =       $this->person->id ; // I have to use it here
        $promHist-> date                =$request->date ;
```

It reutrns null in the above function.

Comment: What is the default value of `person`? Do you call `add_all` in your `addPromHist` before?

Comment: No I don't call `add_all` because I have already called it once before navigating to my `view`. Now I'm saving the records using the same controller. Should it not hold its values?

And I've not given any default values to `$person` ; I've declared it just above my `add_all` function.

Comment: You mean you visited `/add_all/{persId?}` page first and then `/add/prom_hist` page and since you visited `/add_all/{persId?}`and intialized `person` inside that method, it should store it and be available to use when you visit `/add/prom_hist` ?

Comment: `/add/prom_hist` is not a page, it's just a URL of the `post` request which I sent from `/add_all/` page . And I used same controller for all of these requests..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by the answer of [Khayam Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10739750/khayam-khan?tab=profile); I don't know why he removed it, but this was his answer:

> It gives you null because of the stateless nature of HTTP requests.
>
> Each HTTP request to your Laravel application is handled
> independently. This means that for each request, a new instance of
> your controller is created.
>
> What you can do is either create a service class or save that value in
> the session. For Example,
>
> In `add_all` method
>
> ```
> session(['person_id' => $this->person->id]);
> ```
>
> In `addPromHist` method
>
> ```
> $personId = session('person_id');
> $this->person = Pers_info::find($personId);
> ```

Comment: Thank You for mentioning it, I deleted my answer because someone downvoted it and I don't know why someone would do this even I gave the correct and logical answer which resulted in  negative reputations.

Comment: @ADyson Please if you can tell me why someone would do that and what I can do in this ?